# Create a list of elements passing two params to create it

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, caml

I'm studying Caml light.
I'm doing some practice with many exercises. One of this is *create a function to build a list passing as arguments a **number** and the **element** to replicate*.

My code is

```
let rec rep n x = if n >= 0 then x::(rep n-1 x) ;;
```

I got this error on **n-1** :

> This expression is not a function, it cannot be applied.

I don't understand why and how to decrement correctly that number on every recursive call.

Comment: I'm somewhat curious why wouldn't you study F#?

Comment: Because for the last exam at University I have to do something in Caml Light. Is not a choice. I must do it -.-'

Comment: Yeah, as I said I was just curious about the reason. It will make entry into F# easier :)

Comment: So, if I'll wanna learn F# is a good thing begin with Caml Light ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use an industrial strength functional language use F#. Its syntax is based on OCaml but it sits on top of .NET. Drop by http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f when u have time. Or Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around `n-1`, like `(n-1)`.